# how to add two relationships when linking datasources in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have two datasource (2 excel tableus)
1. It has the station id 
2. It's the trip tableau and contains both start_station_id and end_station_id.

Now I want to link them in Tableau by adding relationships. However, the "edit relationship" function only allows me to add one relationship. (either id from table 1 and start_station_id from table 2, or id from table 1 and end_station_id from table 2).

What should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on what your station id is in the first table.
There are two paths you can go down :

1. You could create another column named station id in the second table and extract either the start_station_id or end_station_id - **This is under the assumption that the station_id matches either start or end**.
2. Duplicate the station_id column in the first table.